# argv reads irrelevant charaters in C

Tags: c, argv

I am learning C programming. My program reads irrelevant numbers than what I supply. Any help? Where am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    int i,sum, digit;
if(argc == 1)
{
    printf("\n No arguments specified");
    return 0;
}
for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
    digit = argv[i];
    printf("Argument is: %d", digit);
    //sum += argv[i];
    }
printf("The sum of all numbers is: %d", sum);
return 0;
}
```

Subbu

Comment: if you enable warnings on your compiler, you should get told about things like that. for example, gcc invoked with -Wall will say: `warning: second argument of ‘main’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]` Generally, compiler warnings can save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 8):

Your `main()` is wrong. It should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
                        ^
                        |
                    IMPORTANT!
```

Since the argument vector is an array of string pointers, not an array of characters.

Then, you're invalidly converting the arguments to integer, you need to call e.g. `strtol()` or `sscanf()` to do so. This conversion is necessary since the arguments are passed to your program as an array of strings, and the string `"42"` (for instance) is very different in C from the number `42`.

Note that both the conversion functions I mentioned make it possible to detect if they failed; for instance if the user gives your program non-numerical arguments it's important to detect that and not go ahead and treat them as numbers.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `strtol()`. Don't use `atoi()`, you won't know wether it's failing or parsing a 0.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[i]` is a pointer to a string and not integer. Strings in c are a char arrays

so your program should be

```
digit = atoi(argv[i]);
```

`atoi()` allow to convert string to an integer and it's from `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: atoi is defined on `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 1):

`main(int argc, char argv[])` should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

`main`'s return value indicates how the program exited, hence it should be explicitly set to int. `main`'s second arguments `argv` means "argument vector", hence its type should be `char *[]` or `char **`.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from argv as an integer - you will always get strings in the argv array - it should be defined as `char* argv[]`.  Consider using `atoi( argv[i] )` to get the integer value.